# Prevent user from performing Save, but not SaveAs, on a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I don't want anyone to perform a Save on, but they can perform a SaveAs. The problem I'm running into is that when they do a SaveAs (using a `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` statement rather than File > Save As), it is not using the standard SaveAsUI. So I can't do a `If SaveAsUI = False Then` method.

Here's what I had it place until I realized it doesn't do what I need.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Not SaveAsUI Then
    If Application.UserName <> "Robby" Then
      MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
      Cancel = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if it is to prevent end-user from accidentally saving and overwriting original WorkBook, than you could just make original file Read-Only.

Comment: Using `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` will bypass the `Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: @Robby   Would turning the original workbook into a template be an option?

Comment: @GlennG What do you mean exactly by "template?"

Comment: @GSazheniuk I don't want the workbook to be read-only for me though. I should be able to save it.

Comment: @Robby - I mean saving it as an excel template, either a .xlt or a .xltm file

Comment: Well, a template would inherently mean that no one could perform a Save, right? I wanted it to be where, based on the user's username, they would be able to save.

Comment: @Robby - It wouldn't stop them from saving, but it wouldn't allow them to overwrite the original without specifically opening the original in edit mode.  It would prompt them to Save As in the same manner that it would with a new blank workbook.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding. I saved it as a .xltm file, I made changes to it, and it let me save it.

Comment: @Robby You have to place it in the Templates folder.  For  Office 2010 that location is C:\ Users\ [UserName] \AppData\ Roaming\ Microsoft\ Templates
 
For Office 2013 that location is: C:\ Users\ [UserName] \ Documents\ Custom Office Templates
 
I'm not sure that this is a viable solution for you, it just depends on your application and needs